# ionic angular data not passing properly

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am retrieving json data form a url, and if i output to console  the data is there.. but when i am injecting it to the controller its not working. What did i do wrong?

```
angular.module('starter.notifications', [])
.factory('Notifications', function($http) {
return {
    getAll: function()
    {
      return $http.get(link).then(function(response){
         console.log(response.data);
         notifications =  response.data;
         return notifications;
      });
    }
}
```

My controller

```
.controller('NotificationsCtrl', function($scope, $state, Notifications) {
    $scope.notifications = Notifications.getAll();
})
```

$scope.notifications is null. So i don't understand why thats not working.

UPDATE:
So i now have it passing the data.. but i guess i don't understand how to use it.

Correct/Working code

```
getAll: function()
{
  notifications = ($http.get(link).then(function(response){ return response.data}));
  return notifications;
}
```

So now in my controller when i do

```
console.log(notifications);
```

i get this[image: dataObject]

So how do i use that data? the array of data i want is there... but i can't get it. I thought i could use
  notifications.value but that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is that your are sending two **return** statements in your factory.Change your code to

```
getAll: function()
    {
      var temp = $http.get(link).then(function(response){
         console.log(response.data);
      var notifications =  response.data;
         return notifications;
      });
    }
```

Comment: Ok that worked. I made some adjustments.. now onto the next problem. Accessing the data.

Comment: now to display all the data from the json you need to use the ng-repeat directive like 
<li ng-repeat =" notification in notifications">{{notification.value}}</li>
or else if you dont want to show the complete data then you need to access it by {{notifications[0].value}}

Answer (score 0):

```
   notifications = ($http.get(link)
          .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            console.log(data);
            return data;
          })
          .error(function(err) {
            return err;
          })
  );
  return notifications;
```

need to pass more than a single parameter. Originally i was only passing response vice data,status, headers, config